# Why Node doesn't properly escape string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node, so forgive me if I am asking a dumb question, but I have a string:

```
var myString = 'DOMAIN\\username';
```

and I want to use it in an object as such:

```
var myObject = {
    owner: myString
};
```

So if I do a `console.log(myString)` it shows `'DOMAIN\username'`, but then when I use it in the object it seems that it doesn't escape. The output of myObject would be:

`{ owner: 'DOMAIN\\username }`

I tried double escaping it and possible converting it to special characters too, but that didn't work. Anyone know what I need to do?

**EDIT**

The problem is that I have to use this in a SOAP call, so it's giving an error that states that 'DOMAIN\username' does not exist. I don't really need to console log it, I was just trying to see how the arguments were being formatted before I would send the call. I tried JSON.stringify(myObject) as well and that didn't work either. It is still being transferred as 'DOMAIN\username'

Comment: Console.log "escapes" or rather just doesn't show the double backslash. Try `JSON.stringify(myObject)` and you will see the original string.

Comment: @marekful: Backslashes in strings are escaped in JSON, too. The result of outputting your suggestion would be the string `{"owner":"DOMAIN\\username"}`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to point out. The OP asked why he only sees one backslash in a console.log output.

Comment: please see my update.

Comment: How are you writing your data to the SOAP call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output of myObject would be:
>
> ```
> { owner: 'DOMAIN\\username }
> ```

That's because you're logging it as an object, e.g. via `console.log` or similar, and so it's showing you something source-like for it.

Your string correctly has a single literal backslash in it, both in the `myString` variable and the `myObject.owner` property. The issue is purely how you're outputting your object.

Comment: The problem is that I have to use this in a SOAP call, so it's giving an error that states that 'DOMAIN\\username' does not exist. I don't really need to console log it, I was just trying to see how the arguments were being formatted before I would send the call.

Comment: @AndrewButler: The string only has one backslash in it. If you're running into a problem with the SOAP call, you need to look at how you're writing the string to the SOAP stuff. Simply outputting the string will **not** cause backslashes to be duplicated.

Comment: @AndrewButler The problem with `console.log` is that `util.format` (which is [used by `console.log`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L35-L37)) escapes strings that are part of an object property. Compare `util.format("a\\b")` => `"a\\b"` and `util.format({a:"b\\c"})` => `"{ a: \'b\\\\c\' }"`. The problem *actually* comes from `util.inspect`, used by `format`. Try overwriting `inspect` with `var oldInspect=util.inspect; util.inspect=function() { process.stdout.write("inspect called\n"); oldInspect.call(this, arguments) }` to invstigate if `inspect` causes your issue.